# Centos 6: login as root but see a different user name

Tags: ssh, centos6

I've added a new user (e.g anotheruser) and tried to give this user root permission (and I don't remember what I did). 
When I login as root, it seems that I've logged in as this anotheruser.
How can I correct this?

this is what I see in shell:

```
login as: root
root@x.x.x.x's password:
Last login: Sun Aug 14 11:59:38 2016 from x.x.x.x
anotheruser@main [~]#
```

Comment: This question is better suited for http://serverfault.com, because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow/` files.
It looks like you have changed the name of the user `0` (which is root user).

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8447/how-do-you-rename-root for more details.

Also check what login shell is set for the root user (you can find this in `passwd` file). It might be changed to something that changes the active user from `root` to `anotheruser`.